# How do you adjust and/or mute the audio of a video?

Tags: audio

I'm editing a video for a customer, and I'm using Blender. However, I'm a bit new. They want this as a YouTube video, and they want to completely get rid of the audio and add a voiceover. People are telling me to delete the sound strip, however I don't know which strip that is. I also haven't found any button that, by even the slightest bit, looks like it'll help me detatch the audio. I also need to learn how to make an audio. It would have to be in the form of a video, but then wouldn't the screen have to be a part as well...? Which I don't want. I just want an audio, no extra video strip. Knowing which strip is which would really help; please respond to this ASAP, I need it quickly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a free online video editor to extract audio with a click.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think I know the answer. I've found it and it works! It's at the bottom left; click playback. Near the top of the dropdown menu, it says mute audio. Click that, and it'll be muted! Works for 2.82! Thanks still, to the community, for viewing/trying to answer this question!

Comment: Although, even though I've answered my own question, I would still love it if someone could answer my other questions, the ones other than how to mute a video!